# yoyo-migrations fresh install on conda error

Tags: python, database, postgresql, anaconda

I just recently started having this issue with `yoyo-migrations` https://pypi.org/project/yoyo-migrations/

I am using conda environment and when I install with `pip install yoyo-migrations` and launch, I see the following:

> yoyo
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/cpProj/bin/yoyo", line 7, in 
> from yoyo.scripts.main import main
> File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/cpProj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yoyo/**init**.py", line 27, in 
> from yoyo.connections import get_backend
> File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/cpProj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yoyo/connections.py", line 23, in 
> from .migrations import default_migration_table
> File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/cpProj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yoyo/migrations.py", line 51
> _collectors: MutableMapping[str, "StepCollector"] = (
> ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

If you have a conda environment, you should not use pip.
Try instead:

```
conda install package_name

conda install yoyo-migrations
```

for your particular case.

You may want to run

```
conda update conda
```

to be sure you are up to date